# Keep StepContent Data in Material-ui Stepper when active step changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a `Stepper` which has multiple steps and each step includes many `TextField`s. Now material-ui unmounts step contents when you change your step, so all the data in the `TextField`s will be lost.

Now my question :

Is there anyway to keep/save the data in the `TextField`s while we're changing steps ?

I don't wanna :

- Use redux to save my form's states
- Use any third-party libraries like redux-form
- Save text input datas in the parent component (Stepper)

Here's my vertical Stepper, nothing special :

```
        <Paper style={{padding: 15, marginRight: 19}}>
            <Stepper activeStep={stepIndex} orientation="vertical">
                <Step>
                    <StepLabel>Personnel Info</StepLabel>
                    <StepContent>
                        <PersonalInfo ref="personalInfo"/>
                        {this.renderStepActions()}
                    </StepContent>
                </Step>
                .
                .
                .
            </Stepper>
        </Paper>
```

I'm using:

- Material-UI: 0.15.4
- React: 15.3.0
- Browser: Chrome 52.0.2743.116

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing something very similar to you.  There is probably a better way, but what I have done is to add an "onChange" handler to my StepContent child that returns an object with an id and value, I can then track in the component that contains the stepper.

So your stepper container might look like this:

```
class StepperContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      stepIndex: 0,
    };
    this.handleStepData = this.handleStepData.bind(this);
  }

  handleStepData(data) {
    console.log('data.id',data.id);
    console.log('data.value', data.value);
    this.storeData(data);
  }

  render() {
    <Paper style={{padding: 15, marginRight: 19}}>
        <Stepper activeStep={stepIndex} orientation="vertical">
            <Step>
                <StepLabel>Personnel Info</StepLabel>
                <StepContent>
                    <PersonalInfo ref="personalInfo" onChange={this.handleStepData}/>
                    {this.renderStepActions()}
                </StepContent>
            </Step>
            .
            .
            .
        </Stepper>
    </Paper>
```

And Your `<PersonalInfo>` component will need a method like this:

```
handleChange(event, index, id, value) {
  .
  .
  .
  (Do some local processing)
  .
  .
  .
  this.props.onChange({value,id});
}
```

I haven't dug into Redux or similar yet, but maybe that would be a better way to handle things like this.  They seems to be popping up often as I'm creating a React App and it gets cumbersome to manage.

Answer (score 2):

## 2021  materia ui v5

https://mui.com/components/steppers/#performance

`<StepContent TransitionProps={{ unmountOnExit: false }} />`